# Suppressing warnings about use of SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and AVX instructions in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I've recently installed TensorFlow using pip install on a MacOS. And even though TensorFlow works as expected I still get these warnings about using SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and AVX instructions basically every time I run a script.

The said warnings:

> W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

Inb4 install from sources:

I'm just looking to suppress these particular warnings.

Comment: Voting to re-open; the marked duplicate explains how to compile for these instruction sets, but does not explain how to suppress the warnings, which was the question asked here. If you're running TF on GPUs, it might give a significant improvement to compile for specific CPU instruction sets, and if there is an easy way to suppress the warnings, that might be preferable.

Comment: I agree, this is not dublicate question. For suppress the warnings this code can be used: `import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf`